# Keyboard shortcut to switch from interactions to definitions panel

Tags: racket

Picked up the book "Realm of Racket" today and went through the 1st chapter. What really slows me down in the editor is the need to mouse click to switch panels. Is there a keyboard shortcut to do it? I couldn't find it in the "Keyboard Shortcuts" section on http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/pdf/drracket.pdf .

By the way I've heard that the standard Lisp editor is Emacs. Is the editor that comes with DrRacket based on Emacs?

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer over here: http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2011-September/047857.html

Turns out pressing Control-D or Control-E once or twice does the job.

Comment: You can also use Ctrl+F6 to switch directly.

Answer (score 2):

*Old question, but hopefully this will help someone looking for answers on google.*

To switch from the definitions area to the interactions area in Dr Racket or vice versa:

"Ctrl+F6" on Windows

"Ctrl+x, o" (press control + x at the same time, release, then press o) on Linux. This is the same as switching windows in Emacs.

In Dr Racket go to Edit->Keybindings->Show Active Keybindings and then search for "shift-focus" to see what the shortcut is in your operating system.